# Parallel queries to separate databases

Tags: python, io, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, cx-oracle

I would like to parallelize queries in multiple separate databases.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import cx_Oracle  # db1, db3
import psycopg2  # db2

query1 = 'select * from a'
query2 = 'select * from b'
query3 = 'select * from c'

# functions connect to separate databases (db1, db2, db3) and return query result
def db1(query):
    ....
def db2(query):
    ....
def db3(query):
    ....

def my_func(x):
    if x == 0:
        return db1(query1)
    elif x == 1:
        return db2(query2)
    else:
        return db3(query3)

result = []
pool = mp.Pool(4)  # 3 calls + 1 for processing this code
result.append(pool.map(my_func, [0,1,2]))
print(len(result), len(result[0]), len(result[1]), len(result[2]))
```

I constructed queries which 2 seconds each, so accessing 3 dbs in sequence takes +- 6 seconds. The code above however never seems to finish, nor does memory usage increase in same way as sequential calls.

Before I had `pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())` but that stressed the computer even more, utilizing all cores till 99%. In principle, I know the number of separate databases so can define it (using here the logic of `number of dbs + 1` for processing in example above).

PS: The above code works if there is only one function which does some computation, i.e. my_func calls computation for different x such as `return sum([int(num)**int(num) for num in 5*str(x)])`.

Comment: You only need a pool size of 3 since the main process is processing the results *after* the all the submitted tasks have *finished* processing (assuming you get this to work) and the pool processes are once again idle. Also, `pool.map` returns a `list` and so your are appending to `result` a list and so `len(result)` will be 1 if you are successful. You probably mean `result = pool.map(my_func. [0, 1, 2])`. If you call `my_func` serially in a loop without multiprocessing does it actually work or only if each run does one call at a time (I assume you meant the former, but I want to make sure)?

Comment: You should post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); what is contained within your query functions could be critical. And why should having a pool size > 3 result in more cores being used (this is a rhetorical question; I find this very strange)?